# valgrind on mac El Capitan

Tags: macos, valgrind

I am trying to install valgrind on mac el captain. I used brew and I am successful in installing it. But it failed to link I used brew link valgrind but it says

> "Error: Could not symlink include/valgrind/callgrind.h /usr/local/include/valgrind is not writable."

Answer (score 0):

This is a permissions issue when `brew` attempts to write to /usr/local/

For a resolution, reset the permissions on your /usr/local/ as follows:

```
sudo chown -R `whoami` /usr/local
brew link --overwrite valgrind
```

This is not really a valgrind-specific issue.